# How to get the probabilities of classes in Spark Naive Bayes classifier?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes

I'm training a NaiveBayesModel in Spark, however when I'm using it to predict a new instance I need to get the probabilities for each class. I looked at the code of predict function in NaiveBayesModel and come up with the following code:

```
val thetaMatrix = new DenseMatrix (model.labels.length,model.theta(0).length,model.theta.flatten,true)
val piVector = new DenseVector(model.pi)
//val prob = thetaMatrix.multiply(test.features)

val x = test.map {p =>       
  val prob = thetaMatrix.multiply(p.features)          
  BLAS.axpy(1.0, piVector, prob)
  prob
}
```

Does this work properly? The line `BLAS.axpy(1.0, piVector, prob)` keeps giving me an error that the value 'axpy' is not found.

Comment: or is there any way that I can calculate the probabilities using the pi and theta

Answer (score 2):

In a recent [pull-request](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/7376/files) this was added to the Spark trunk and will be released in Spark 1.5 (closing [SPARK-4362](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-4362)). you can therefore call

`def predictProbabilities(testData: RDD[Vector]): RDD[Vector]`

or

`def predictProbabilities(testData: Vector): Vector`

Comment: Hi. I am also facing the same issue. However, I cannot upgrade to Spark 1.5. I have to stick on Spark 1.1.0. Can you please provide some hints on how to implement this in Spark 1.1.0?