# How to get probabilities (instead of a single - actual - class) from NaiveBayesModel in MLlib?

Tags: apache-spark, classification, apache-spark-mllib, naivebayes

I have built a NaiveBayesModel in MLlib. It works fine but I would like to get back the probabilities of each class for given input instead of the model's final - and single - decision, that is, whether the input belongs to class 1.0 or class 0.0. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think they support this yet, but I know is in their roadmap to add probabilities to several classifiers prediction outputs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's right. Spark 1.5 will support this on Naive Bayes. My problem however is that I am using Spark 1.1.0 and I cannot update so I have to find a workaround. Any ideas? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31842502/how-to-get-the-probabilities-of-classes-in-spark-naive-bayes-classifier

Comment: That is something that needs to be saved when computing the model, with access to the code one could do it for sure. If I were you I would check some implementation of Naive Bayes that has that implementation, just as an example, and then check here for how is it implemented, then make changes to get it to output that. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/classification/NaiveBayes.scala